# Spring injection not working for FF4J web console

Tags: java, spring, ff4j

I am try to get the FF4j ([ff4j.org](http://ff4j.org/)) web console to work. According to the documentation on the website, I use the following configuration:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ff4j-console</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.ff4j.web.embedded.ConsoleServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>ff4jProvider</param-name>
        <param-value><path to class>.ConsoleFF4jProvider</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ff4j-console</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ff4j-console</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My implementation of `FF4JProvider` is:

```
import org.ff4j.FF4j;
import org.ff4j.web.api.FF4JProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 * Created by itaykl on 17/06/2015.
 */
@Component
public class ConsoleFF4jProvider implements FF4JProvider{

    @Autowired
    private FF4j ff4j;

    public ConsoleFF4jProvider() {
    }

    @Override
    public FF4j getFF4j() {
        return ff4j;
    }
}
```

My problem is that no matter what I do I cannot get the autowiring of `ff4j` to work. Whenever the `ConsoleServlet` gets to the method call of `getFF4J()`, the `ff4j` class member is `null`.

I have tried using several other servlets together with the FF4J console and tried defining the `ff4j` bean in several ways.

Currently it is defined as:

```xml
<bean id="ff4j" class="org.ff4j.FF4j" ></bean>
```

But nothing seems to work.

If anyone found a solution to this problem and can share it, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I've got the similar problem with DI. The reason was that my `@Component` class was initialized before `@Autowired` class. Can you also add the bean definition of your `ConsoleFF4jProvider` class? Is it made in the same pace as `<bean id="ff4j" class="org.ff4j.FF4j" ></bean>`?

Comment: There is no bean definition it is just annotated

Comment: Your `ConsoleFF4jProvider` is initialized before constructor of `FF4j`. I'll add more info en some minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was saying in my comments, the constructor of `FF4j` wasn't invoked yet when you are trying to access to bean in `ConsoleFF4jProvider`. It is because Spring loads first `ConsoleFF4jProvider` and not beans defined in `web.xml`. To solve this problem you can remove:

```
@Autowired
private FF4j ff4j;
```

and modify your `getFF4j()` function as following:

```
@Override
public FF4j getFF4j() {
    final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    context.register(FF4j.class); 
    context.refresh();

    FF4j ff4j= context.getBean(FF4j.class);
    return ff4j;
}
```

Or you can initialize ff4j in constructor as well.

**Edit:**
Otherwise you can add

```
SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
```

to the constructor of `ConsoleFF4jProvider`

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: This was able to instantiate FF4j, however when I try to change the bean configuration e.g.  <bean id="ff4j" class="org.ff4j.FF4j" >
  <property name="store" ref="ff4j.store.jdbc" />
 </bean>


 <bean id="ff4j.store.jdbc" class="org.ff4j.store.JdbcFeatureStore" autowire="constructor"/> it didn't work. seems that it just instantiates FF4j using the default constructor every time

Comment: Basically this is the same as just doing FF4j ff4j = new FF4j();

Comment: Well, I've done some more investigation and found that you can add `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` to constructor of `ConsoleFF4jProvider`. And then you can leave `FF4j` as `Autowired`.

Comment: It worked!! thanks a lot mate I was stuck on it for days. post your last comment as an answer so I can check it as correct.

Comment: You are welcome, I've also tried `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);` for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

**Spring 4 injection works with @Configuration class and @Autowired**

The problem is the servlet is initialized by Jetty (your servlet container), that's why ConsoleFF4jProvider is not aware of Spring context.

With this example you can still use Spring injection mechanism with @Autowired.

You need to :

1. Add a Spring listener in web.xml.
2. Create a Java class to handle the bean FF4j.
3. Inject the Spring context in ConsoleFF4jProvider.

**web.xml :**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <display-name>HelloWorld ff4j app</display-name>

     <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Configuration using @Configuration classes -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>foo.bar.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ff4j-console</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.ff4j.web.embedded.ConsoleServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ff4jProvider</param-name>
            <param-value>foo.bar.ConsoleFF4jProvider</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ff4j-console</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ff4j-console</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
package foo.bar;

import org.ff4j.FF4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public FF4j getFF4j() {
        return new FF4j("ff4j.xml");
    }
}
```

**ConsoleFF4jProvider.java updated**

```
package foo.bar;

import org.ff4j.FF4j;
import org.ff4j.web.api.FF4JProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.SpringBeanAutowiringSupport;

public class ConsoleFF4jProvider implements FF4JProvider {

    @Autowired
    private FF4j ff4j;

    /**
     * Inject the appropriate Spring bean FF4j declared into
     * {@link ApplicationConfig}. Property {@code ff4j} marked with @Autowired
     * annotation will work.
     */
    public ConsoleFF4jProvider() {
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }

    @Override
    public FF4j getFF4j() {
        return ff4j;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it's working like below in case of referring FF4J in servlet container. Just override configure function and source the FF4jConfig class where your FF4j is defined.

```
@Configuration 
public class FF4jWebConsoleConfiguration extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(FF4JConfig.class); //scan
    }
    
    // autowired working here
    @Bean
    public FF4jDispatcherServlet ff4jDispatcherServlet(@Autowired FF4j ff4j) {
...
}
```